# Enable JMX over TCP (JMXMP) in Spring app

Tags: spring, jmx, visualvm

I'd like enable JMXMP in Spring application running locally.

**application.properties**:

```
spring.jmx.enabled=true
spring.jmx.url=service:jmx:jmxmp://localhost:9875/
```

**SampleAppConfig.java**:

```
import com.app.config.properties.SampleAppProperties;
import com.app.exception.InternalErrorException;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jmx.support.ConnectorServerFactoryBean;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableConfigurationProperties({SampleAppProperties.class})
@Configuration
public class SampleAppConfig implements InitializingBean {

    @Value("${spring.jmx.url}")
    private String jmxUrl;

    @Value("${log4j2.formatMsgNoLookups:#{null}}")
    private Boolean formatMsgNoLookups;

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.jmx",name = "enabled",havingValue = "true",matchIfMissing = false)
    public ConnectorServerFactoryBean connectorServerFactoryBean() throws Exception {
        final ConnectorServerFactoryBean connectorServerFactoryBean = new ConnectorServerFactoryBean();
        connectorServerFactoryBean.setServiceUrl(jmxUrl);
        return connectorServerFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

**Running app:**

```
java -Xms128m -Xmx2048m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow  -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true com.app.SampleAppApplication
```

I'm trying to connect to VisualVM via service:jmx:jmxmp://localhost:1099/ and getting error: `Unavailable application defined by a JMX connection`.

Any ideas?

[image]